# presentViewController is not showing mail composer sheet

Tags: objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

presentViewController is not showing the mail modalview controller. I have changed from presentmodalviewcontroller to presentViewController, but it was not giving any error nor it is presenting the modalview. How to fix this issue?

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self; 
    picker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:0.33 brightness:0.69 alpha:0];
    NSString *lObjstringPtr = (NSString *)nil;

    if(OPPORTUNITY_ENTITY_OBJECT_TYPE_CODE==m_cobjOwningGroup.m_cObjSelectedEntity.m_cObjectTypeCode) {
        lObjstringPtr = [lObjstringPtr stringByAppendingFormat:@" To Follow Up"];
        [picker setSubject:lObjstringPtr];
        lObjstringPtr = (NSString *)nil;
    } else 
        [picker setSubject:@""];

        [picker setMessageBody:m_cObjemailBodyStrPtr isHTML:NO];
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:pEmailID];
        [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil]; 
        [picker release];
```

Comment: Please provide code of what you have done so far. Help us Help you

Comment: I am not able to edit the question as stackoverflow has the 5 point or some restriction for editing..Please help me and edit.

Comment: Well you were able to add your code through editing.

Comment: @Popeye's edit added curly braces after the else.  You might check to see whether that code change fixes the problem.

Comment: @DavidGorsline that's a good point I assumed he just missed it out copying which I shouldn't have done. But yes he should try putting them in.

Comment: @user2186457 You can leave braces out like that but I wouldn't recommend it. Mainly for readability purposes.

Comment: That is to set mail subject i am doing some validation,If code is something in if then set some subject else set empty subject.And I am doing message body,recipients and all.Actually else part has only 1 line of code

Comment: @user2186457 I know just for readability it is better to do `if(condition) { code... } else { code... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things, one specific to this case, one a general point.

1. You don't appear to be checking whether mail is set up on your device. Before you try to display the mail view you should check the return value of [`[MFMailComposeViewController  canSendMail]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) and only show the controller if it's `YES`
2. A common case for a view not showing is that the controller is `nil`. Before `presentViewController:` you might want to check (with an `NSLog` or using a debugger) that `picker` is not zero.

Comment: Yes,I have tested canSendmail and checked the viewcontroller for nil both are succeded,But I tihink that is not the issue.It is not showing the mail composer sheet.

Comment: Anybody please provide me the solution.... Please